# mismatched input '.' in rule

Tags: drools, rule-engine, kie

I am new to drools .I am writing a new rule.But i am getting Error as follow:

> mismatched input '.' in rule "StopTextRule" in pattern

My rule is

```
package com.******.*****;

import java.lang.Number;

rule "StopTextRule"
    dialect "mvel"
    salience 20
    lock-on-active true
    when
        RoutingData( messageBody != null && (
                        (messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("stop") || messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("\"stop\"") || messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("stop.") || messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("\"stop.\"")) 
                            || (messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("quit")|| messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("\"quit\"") || messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("quit.")|| messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("\"quit.\""))
                            || (messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("cancel")|| messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("\"cancel\"") || messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("cancel.")|| messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("\"cancel.\""))
                            || (messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("UNSUBSCRIBE")|| messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("\"UNSUBSCRIBE\"") || messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("UNSUBSCRIBE.")|| messageBody.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("\"UNSUBSCRIBE.\"")))
                            && incomingMessageProtocol != null && incomingMessageProtocol.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("X"))
        routingResp : RoutingRuleResponse( isStop == false )
    then
        modify( routingResp ) {
                setIsStop( true )
        }
end
```

Comment: Which Drools version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This compiles using Drools 6.4.0. I think that you are using an older version where Java expressions had to be enclosed in `eval`.

It would be simpler in any case to rewrite this pattern like so:

```
rule x
when
   X( messageBody != null &&
      messageBody matches "\\s*(\"?)(?i:stop|quit|cancel|unsubscribe)\\.?\\1\\s*" &&
      incomingMessageProtocol != null &&
      incomingMessageProtocol matches "\\s*(?i:X)\\s*") )
then
   // ...
end
```